# Bubble Sorting List Sorting Returns None In Python

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I am trying to learn how the bubble sorting algorithm works in python.
However sorting the list returns `None` when i print out the output.

Here Is My Code

```
arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "Z", "Y"]


def _sort(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            if nums[j] > nums[j+1]:
                temp = nums[j+1]
                nums[j+1] = temp

    
_sorted = _sort(arr)
print(_sorted)
```

Here Is Output When I Print Out The Result.

```
None
```

Comment: You have forgotten to return the list. Add `return nums`

Comment: Also, your function argument is `nums` but you're looping over `arr`. Fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the algorithm is not right. You should do something like this:

```py
def _sort(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            if nums[j] > nums[i]:
                temp = nums[i]
                nums[i] = nums[j]
                nums[j] = temp
```

Second, the function does not return anything. That is why it returns `None`. However, the list `arr` is now sorted. You can check it by running this code:

```py
arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "Z", "Y"]


def _sort(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-1, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            if nums[j] > nums[i]:
                temp = nums[i]
                nums[i] = nums[j]
                nums[j] = temp
                

_sort(arr)  # This function does not return anything
print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks For The Notice.
I actually changed it in editor before posting it here.

Comment: Check out my code for the algorithm. Yours does not modify the list.

Comment: Thanks Man. It Worked Although I Had Another Confusing Method Which Did Work, Your's Is Much Simpler.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include a return nums.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the function return, therefore it just returns `None`.

```
def _sort(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums)-1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i):
      if nums[j] > nums[j+1]:
        temp = nums[j+1]
        nums[j+1] = temp
  return nums
```

This should do the trick.
Just for completeness:

- Instead of returning anything, you should also be able to just access `arr` again after your function call.
- You have still some fundamental errors in your algorithm

Comment: I now got a new error. Thanks For The Help. It Returned The Array Instead Of None.

Comment: You forgot to actually swap the values. This may be why your result is still the same as before.

Comment: Yes I Did Forget. Thanks For The Notice

Answer (score 1):

you havent returned anything ..ie return nums

Answer (score 0):

Your `_sort` function attempts to sort your array "in place", meaning it operates directly on the given array without creating a new array. As such the function doesn't need to return anything, and indeed yours doesn't. So by writing `_sorted = _sort(arr)`, the variable `_sorted` is assigned to `None` because `_sort` doesn't return anything. If you instead wrote the following,

```
# _sorted = _sort(arr)
_sort(arr)
print(arr)
```

You should see your array was modified.

Comment: Actually it behaved just as you predicted but modifying it didn't help either as the array wasn't modified but returned the output in the same order